# in Compat.php line 1946 : this is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP

Tags: installation, centos, php, redhat-enterprise-linux, magento

I'm triying to install Magento 2.4.2 open source on a Centos 8 server RHEL version but I have a little problem... I put the screenshot in attached files, thanks you for just ideas of search...

[image: installation magento]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same error has an excellent answer in the StackExchange post
[This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331992).

> This error occurs with Magento 2.4.2 when php *does not* include the
> `sodium` php extension.
>
> You can check if this extension is installed with
>
> ```
> php -i | grep sodium
> sodium support => enabled
> libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
> ```
>
> To fix this problem install / activate the `sodium` php extension.
>
> For Xampp in `php.ini` add (or uncomment)
>
> ```
> extension=sodium;
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> sudo apt install php-libsodium
> ```
>
> **NOTE the supported PHP version for Magento 2.4 is PHP 7.4**

Comment: yes it was that, I installed sodium and it works. Thanks you.